# Sending data from list of items c#

Tags: c#, list, sockets, client-server

I have a list which holds numerous messages which I'm trying to send to my server. 
This is my code:

```
    private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listORequestedCommands.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            clientSock.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(listORequestedCommands.Items[i].ToString()));
        }
        removeAll_Click(sender, e);
        sendBtn.Enabled = false;
    }
```

However, when I click the send button, I see that the server receives one message, which contains all those list items concatenated, instead of receiving the messages separated.

Any ideas?

Comment: What type is `clientSock`?

Comment: Separated _how_ ?  Send a NewLine or whatever after each message.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a protocol. TCP sockets are stream-based, not message-based.

Comment: Idanis, what CodeCaster means is that TCP doesn't respect message boundaries. Sending 4 bytes separately 1200 times is the same as sending 4800 bytes in one call (to the receiving end). You will have to add some sort of grammar (i.e. implement a protocol) to parse and delimit your messages. A basic example is prefixing each message with a 4 byte integer length so that you know where the message ends and the next begins.

Comment: Answering to you all. `clientSock` is a `Socket`. Jason and CodeCaster, what I don't understand is this: When I click send, with one message, it's being sent, then, while still connected, I just replace that message with a new one, still having one message, and I click send again, the new message is being sent again properly. How this is different from what I'm doing?

Comment: @Idanis this gets asked quite regularly, if I find some time I'll try to look up or create a reference question / community wiki for this. Bottomline: one `send()` on one side does not result in one `receive()` on the other side. This is caused by the Nagle algorithm, but simply disabling that won't solve your problem. If you prepend each message with 4 bytes (`Int32` or `int`) describing the message length, the server can first read the length N and then read N bytes.

Comment: Trying to search for solutions like you stated.

Comment: @Idanis take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761509/c-sharp-best-way-to-differentiate-socket-messages, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203930/c-sharp-streaming-sockets-how-to-separate-messages

Comment: Ok, I'm still trying to implement it. Just one more question. Can a solution be this as well: instead of sending each item in the list to the server, just send the entire list, as an object, then receive the list on the other side, and then iterate the items?

Comment: @Idanis that is possible, but then still you need some kind of protocol. There are bytes flowing over the wire, not objects or messages. All that knowledge is lost as soon as something is put on the wire. You can use the [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) to serialize your list and then deserialize that on the other end; then still you'd need a size prefix because your server doesn't know how large the list object is and thus how many bytes it must read.

Comment: If you don't use a size prefix (or other forms of protocol), the receiving end never will know the boundaries (how large is this item; when is it completely received; where does the next item start) and cannot parse incoming data. It might work well with low volumes or large timeouts, but as soon as it is put in use it will explode. Just use a size prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for acknowledgement, Since you are not waiting the  bytes are  getting collected and displayed as consolidated results. 
After sending data to socket you should use code like

```
int bytesRec = clientSock.Receive(bytes);
```

Following this URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx